# evaluating accuracy of decision tree/forrest model

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

Im relatively new to ML. Ive created a decision tree model to predict prices of an item based on some criteria.

For an example, lets say the model predicts the price of a car based on a few features such as engine size, number of doors, fuel type, mileage and age.

Analysis of the data showed me that my data was not linear, so decision tree was a better fit. The model also does an ok job at predicting but before i can give it to any users, i need to quantify its accuracy.

As its non linear, R squared doesnt seem liek a good method of assessing accuracy, but im unsure what i should use.

Appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, what you can usually do is to assess the performance of the model against a test or hold-out set (not used during the construction of the model), using a evaluation metric.

For regression problems (like the ones you are describing) there are several [evaluation metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) available. The most common ones are MAE ([Mean Absolute Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error)) and RMSE ([Root Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation))

To fully understand how good the performance of your model is, you can then compare it against other models, or against simple baselines (like predicting always the average price, or returning the price of the most similar car in the training set).